# Javascript, issue in reading json with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like this:

```
[
  {
    "Code": 100
  },
  {
    "Drivers": [
      {
        "RowID": "1",
        "DriverName": "ZZ",
        "DriverAlias": "FF",
        "DriverEmail": "YY@gmail.com",
        "DriverPhone": "1121112229"
      },
      {
        "RowID": "3",
        "DriverName": "OO",
        "DriverAlias": "EE",
        "DriverEmail": "kkk@gmail.com",
        "DriverPhone": "12121458474"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm reading the json in Javascript like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
 Drivers[i] = {
  RowID: data[1].Drivers[i].RowID,
  DriverName: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverName,
  DriverAlias: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverAlias,
  DriverEmail: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverEmail,
  DriverPhone: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverPhone
 };
}
```

It's working but when I have my json only with one Driver like this:

```
[
  {
    "Code": 100
  },
  {
    "Drivers": [
      {
        "RowID": "1",
        "DriverName": "ZZ",
        "DriverAlias": "FF",
        "DriverEmail": "YY@gmail.com",
        "DriverPhone": "1121112229"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's not working , am I reading the json in a wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: can you change line RowID: data[1].Drivers[i].RowID to RowID: data[0].Drivers[i].RowID

Comment: You are iterating over the `data.length` but you want to iterate over `data[0].Drivers.length`

Comment: TypeError: data[0].Drivers is undefined  RowID: data[0].Drivers[i].RowID,  Not working with the [0] instead of [1]

Comment: data[0].Drivers.length  ??? What do you suggest  Beterraba ?

Comment: data[1].Drivers.length - pls see my answer. data[0] is 'Code':100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - you need to check the length of data[1].Drivers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].Drivers.length; i++) {  
 Drivers[i] = {
  RowID: data[1].Drivers[i].RowID,
  DriverName: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverName,
  DriverAlias: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverAlias,
  DriverEmail: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverEmail,
  DriverPhone: data[1].Drivers[i].DriverPhone
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code a lot, by doing this:

```
var Drivers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].Drivers.length; i++) {  
    Drivers[i] = {};
    for (var j in data[1].Drivers[i]) {
        Drivers[i][j] = data[1].Drivers[i][j];
    }
}
```

That will automatically go through every object in the `data[1].Drivers` array, and copy over everything from those objects. This would also automatically copy over any other values that are stored in the json.